# Python/scrapy nested for/if loop working incorrectly

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to crawl for a list of users and their SteamID from www.tf2items.com/profiles/.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
import scrapy

bot_words = [
"bot",
"BOT",
"[tf2mart]"
]

class AccountSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "accounts"
    start_urls = [  
'file:///Users/max/Documents/promotebot/tutorial/tutorial/TF2ITEMS.htm'
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    for tr in response.css("tbody"):
        user = response.css("span a").extract()
        print(user)
        if bot_words not in response.css("span a").extract():
            for href in response.css("span a::attr(href)").extract():
                #yield response.follow("http://www.backpack.tf" + href, self.parse_accounts)
                print("this is a value")
```

My final goal is for this code to print something like:

> a href="/profiles/76561198042757507">Kchypark
>
> this is a value
>
> a href="/profiles/76561198049853548">Agen Kolar
>
> this is a value
>
> a href="/profiles/76561198036381323">Grave Shifter15
>
> this is a value

With this current code, I could even expect

> a href="/profiles/76561198042757507">Kchypark
>
> this is a value
>
> this is a value
>
> this is a value
>
> a href="/profiles/76561198049853548">Agen Kolar
>
> this is a value
>
> this is a value
>
> this is a value
>
> a href="/profiles/76561198036381323">Grave Shifter15
>
> this is a value
>
> this is a value
>
> this is a value

However, I get:

> a href="/profiles/76561198042757507">Kchypark
>
> a href="/profiles/76561198049853548">Agen Kolar
>
> a href="/profiles/76561198036381323">Grave Shifter15
>
> this is a value
>
> this is a value
>
> this is a value

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which value you are trying to scrape? It matters. Do this value is located on different page? Also can you update question and add full spider code in it.

Comment: In your for loop you still use response. Assuming you want to get data from the `tbody` I'd expect you to use `tr.css(SELECTOR)` instead.

Comment: Daniel M, updated. The value is on the same page.

Comment: @DanielM updated. The value is on the same page.

Comment: @memecreep why do you tried to use `yield respnse.follow` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first print outputing a list of `href`s

```
user = response.css("span a").extract()
print(user)
```

your code should looks like

```
def parse(self, response):
    for tr in response.css("tbody"):
        for user in response.css("span a"):
            if bot_words not in user:
                print(user.extract())
                href = user.css('::attr(href)').extract()[0]
                print(href)
                #yield response.follow("http://www.backpack.tf" + href, self.parse_accounts)
                print("this is a value")
```

Also, Best practice in srapy is using of [items](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) instead of raw `print` function.

And be aware of code duplication like `response.css("span a").extract()`